# Accessing Aggregate Entities without Lazy Loading

Tags: domain-driven-design, lazy-loading, entities

I want to follow the DDD philosophy and not access entity objects of an aggregate directly. So, i have to call the root object to get the associated entity. But In other cases I dont always want every associated entity to load  when the root is called. Is that the purpose of lazy loading?

How do I access entity objects through the root without loading all the associated objects everytime if i disable lazyloading feature of linq?

EDIT:

For example, If I have a Person as the Root Entity, and the Person has Name, Addresses and OwnedProperties. If I want to get a list of People so that I could display their names, I dont necvessarily want to load up Owned Properties every time on the call to the Repository. Conversely, on another page I may want to show a list of OwnedProperties, but do not want the other information to load with the call. what is the simple way of just calling the Person without the owned property entity other than creating a new person object without that owned properties?

Comment: can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: Probably not. DDD is one of those vague set of principles that has no actual examples.

Comment: @Cletus, there are plenty of concrete examples .. see the Evans book ...

Comment: It's a worrying sign when both the domain abstractions and the system abstractions are so conceptual that you can't easily recognize what is being referred to. Good example of the infamous principle "Just add another abstraction layer." or "One Ring To Rule Them All."

Answer (score 1):

I don't thinks that's possible without lazy loading.

- Getting all data at once: Eager Loading
- Getting data when accessed:   Lazy Loading

Answer (score 1):

According to your edit:
What I do in these situations, is create a 'View' class or a 'DTO' class which just contains the properties that I'm interested in.
For instance, I could have a 'PersonView' class which just has a Name property for instance.

Then, using my OR/M mapper (I use NHibernate), I create a HQL query (or Criteria query) which works on my 'Person' entity.  Before I execute the query, I tell NHibernate that I want 'PersonView' objects as a result (I specify a projection).  Then, NHibernate is smart enough to execute a query that only retrieves the columns that are necessary to populate the PersonView instances.

Comment: in your case, wouldnt your repository have to have overloads for each scenario, and then decide which method to call in repository?

Comment: How exactly do you mean ?  I would have a method in my repository which is called 'FindPersons' for instance, which returns 'PersonView' instances.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid lazy loading is just using the object 'id'